# Why would one save the serialized object in the database?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Why would one save the serialized object in the database as binary instead of separating in simple datatypes?

Comment: efficiency? not all objects are "easy" to instantiate, and sometimes it's easier to use a bit of extra space to store the entire object and its internal state than it is to waste bunch of cpu cycles to rebuild it from scratch from the individual stored values.

Comment: Likewise a custom datatype is still a flat record.  What if you're serializing a list of objects?  What if the schema/layout of the object is dynamic?  There are many reasons to do this and I don't think this question will have an exact "right" answer"

Comment: Because they're not using a document database. ^.^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize and store an object hierarchy -- e.g. a parent object and its children -- in a single column, where traditionally such a relationship would require storing in multiple tables.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to do any operations with the data in the dbms (i.e. all queries will fetch the whole object) it would be efficient to store it as a serialized object. You can always normalize your data (even if it's hierarchical or a list) but if you always fetch the whole thing you could skip some db operations (e.g. JOIN) by storing your object (almost) ready to be used.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be that they are storing a variety of types in one data table and have a field that determines the type.  Another reason is that the you may need to support multiple version of the object with one table.  It is a perfectly acceptable solution in some cases.